# How to run OnPhotonPlayerConnected twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

In my script, I assign a spawn point to a player when they join the game, with this:

```
public void OnPhotonPlayerConnected(PhotonPlayer newPlayer) {
    spawnpoint = GameObject.Find("spawnpoint2");
}
```

However, this will assign `spawnpoint2` to the second player that joins, and then all other players that join after them. I have 3 players that will be in the game, so is there any way to run this function again for the third player?

Answer (score 0):

OnPhotonPlayerConnected called when a remote player entered the room.
Use OnJoinedRoom to handle local player room join.